# VBA Delete query not being executed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a quirk with my Access app that I cannot debug.
I have a form that essentially makes an insertion into a 'completed' table and a deletion from a 'pending' table. Design preferences aside, this is how I'm doing it rather than having some sort of 'Status' column.

I'll summarize my code with the relevent lines.

First it makes the insertion into the completed table, then the simple deletion:

```
    qr = "DELETE * FROM tblPendingClasses WHERE ((tblPendingClasses.ID = " & curr         & "));" 'build the query
    Debug.Print qr
    MsgBox (qr)
    dbMine.Execute qr, dbFailOnExecute

     Form.Refresh 'refresh,requery
     Form.Requery
     MsgBox ("Class review complete.")
     docmd.close
```

The query is built fine, from the debug statement and msgbox, but it just doesn't do anything. I look at the table for pending classes, and the class with the ID I'm trying to delete is just sitting there. No meaningful errors, nothing. This used to work, and works sometimes, but is not working at the moment.

Ideas?

Comment: what is your datatype for the `curr` variable? Also, what is it for `ID` field in `tblPendingClasses`. If it is not a number, you will need to put `'`s arround the `curr` variable, like so: `((tblPendingClasses.ID = '" & curr         & "'));"`

Comment: ID and curr are both numbers, matching data types. I found out what the problem is, thanks.

Comment: @Scotch Just a quick observation, as delete queries only action rows and not individual columns, you don't need to specify **DELETE * FROM**, **DELETE FROM** will be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your module includes `Option Explicit`, you should get a compile error, "Variable not defined" on this line:

```
dbMine.Execute qr, dbFailOnExecute
```

Probably you intended `dbFailOnError` instead of `dbFailOnExecute` as the  option for the `.Execute` method.  Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section of your code module so the VBA compiler will alert you when you attempt to use the name of a constant which doesn't exist (`dbFailOnExecute`).  Then compile and fix any other issues the compiler complains about.

The *Database.Execute Method* help topic recommends:
"*... always use the dbFailOnError option when using the Execute method to run an update or delete query. This option generates a run-time error and rolls back all successful changes if any of the records affected are locked and can't be updated or deleted.*"

So `dbFailOnExecute` will give you the run-time error message which explains why the expected deletions didn't happen.

After making those changes, if you still don't get any rows deleted and no error message, make sure you don't have `SetWarnings` switched off.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: I changed it to failOnError. I still didn't get any informative error message. I did just figure out what the problem was. Somehow a blank record (aside from a foreign key) was added to a related table. When I manually went in to attempt to delete the record, it warned me that it cannot be deleted because there are related records in "xxx". I'm not sure why it wouldn't have told me that at runtime though. Anyways, that was the problem -- a random junk record with a foreign key to the record in question.

Comment: Check `SetWarnings` has not been switched off.

Comment: FailOnError and setting the warnings to true provided the error message I needed to figure this out. Thanks. Now I need to figure out how someone put that dirty foreign key in there.

Comment: Suggest you also find out who turned `SetWarnings` off and find some way to effectively persuade them never to do it again.  ;-)

Comment: That...may have been me :p. I've been catching errors and logging them and getting them emailed to me rather than having them confuse the users. For some reason, this one was not being caught. I think maybe the Error object is only vba errors and err.description won't catch database errors such as constraint/integrity violations?

Comment: OK, search your code for `SetWarnings` and make sure you're not turning it off anywhere.  If you have a situation where you believe you need it off, post a question so one of us can explain why you don't.  A challenge with DML (insert, update, delete) statements is they can fail without a trappable error unless you add `dbFailOnError`.  And when `SetWarnings` is off, that error is discarded silently --- you never get to trap it.

Comment: Well, I never turned SetWarning to false. All i did was defer all errors to my handling function (on error goto handler, and in handler clause, call some functions). I guess the issue was that I didn't initially specify dFailOnError, I used dbFailOnExecute. So, will VBA not catch DML errors in the Error object? dbFailOnError only says that it rolls back updates if an error occurs, it doesn't say that it will throw the error. Since I never turned SetWarnings off, shouldn't I have recieved a referential integrity error at runtime?

Comment: Read the rest of that help topic (emphasis mine): "*In a Microsoft Access workspace , if you provide a syntactically correct SQL statement and have the appropriate permissions, the Execute method won't fail — even if not a single row can be modified or deleted. Therefore, always use the dbFailOnError option when using the Execute method to run an update or delete query. **This option generates a run-time error** and rolls back all successful changes if any of the records affected are locked and can't be updated or deleted.*"

Comment: +1 --exactly what I was wondering. This quote summarizes the problem in question. Maybe add that to your answer since it's being collapsed in the comments?